# Sorting, counting and filtering for dictionary with tuple values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have iterator in which it gives me the version naming, user name(s) and size affiliated with it.
I made it into a dictionary while making the user name and size as a tuple as a value in the dict.

```
gen_dict = {
    "item_A_v004": ["jack", "1"],
    "item_A_v007": ["jack", "10"],
    "item_A_v009": ["jack", "1000"],
    "item_A_v008": ["jack", "100"],
    "item_B_v001": ["kay", "200"],
    "item_B_v003": ["peter", "2200"],
    "item_B_v005": ["kay", "20"],
    "item_C_v004": ["kay", "3"]
}
```

This is the output I got:

```
| item_A_v(xxx) |     4 |                                    jack [1111 (4)] |
| item_B_v(xxx) |     3 |                    kay [223 (2)], peter [2200 (1)] |
| item_C_v(xxx) |     1 |                                      kay [223 (1)] |
```

This is the code:

```
asset_user_dict = defaultdict(set)
asset_count = defaultdict(int)
user_ver_count = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

asset_size_dict = {}


for vers_name, artist_alias in gen_dict.iteritems():
    strip_version_name = vers_name[:-3]
    asset_user_dict[strip_version_name].add(artist_alias[0])
    asset_count[strip_version_name] += 1
    user_ver_count[artist_alias[0]][strip_version_name] += 1

    # This is my problem here...
    # Seems to be summing up all the data found under 1 user
    asset_size_dict.setdefault(artist_alias[0], []).append(artist_alias[1])


for version_name, version_count in sorted(asset_count.iteritems()):  
    users = ', '.join('{0} [{1} ({2}]'.format(alias, convert_size_query(sum(int(i) for i in asset_size_dict.get(alias))), user_ver_count[alias][version_name]) for alias in asset_user_dict[version_name])
    #print users
    print "| {0:<100} | {1:>12} | {2:>50} |".format(version_name+"(xxx)",
                                                    version_count,
                                                    users
                                                    )
```

It seems that if I have same user names (see `kay`) between versions, the overall sum of the size is being outputted instead. So in the above example, I am expecting Kay's Item_B to be 220 and item_C to be 3 but I got 223 for both.

I tried several ways of using more dictionaries but I have either made myself more confused or I simply could not find a 'link' as I wanted to achieve the following:

1. Collate similar version namings into 1
2. Prior to #1, any user names affiliated with the similar versions will be outputted besides it
3. Prior to #2, it will also derive the overall size that each user occupies as well as the number of versions the user have

So far I seem to be able to do for all points but I am definitely missing out a few steps to achieve this 'same user' issue and sorting the third column in descending order by using the size.

What other better ways are there for me to tackle on this problem?

Comment: What code/tools are you using to produce that output? It's impossible to comment usefully on code you haven't shown us. You also haven't provided the example output you _want_; you've described it, but it's helpful to actually paste _exactly_ what you want so there is no risk of misinterpretation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger My bad! Forgot to paste it in here, it has been edited